# Is it possible to use ".gitignore" from the remote during a pull?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-pull

I have a situation where some files that were previously checked into Git now need to be ignored. To ignore them I added the files to ".gitignore" and did the following:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add --all
git commit -m "Removed files from git tracking that should be ignored"
git push
```

Now I have a situation where I need to pull these ".gitignore" changes to another server, but when I do a `git pull` the files that were just added to ".gitignore" are not ignored, and instead they get removed entirely!

I think what is happening is during the pull it is using the local ".gitignore" file that does not ignore these files... and it detects that these files are no longer in git so it just removes them. If I add the files back manually and do another git pull then it begins working properly (now that the correct ".gitignore" file is on the server.)

Is there any way to tell the `git pull` to use the ".gitignore" file from the remote server instead of the local file that way these files get properly ignored and do not get removed on a git pull?

Comment: No need to think about remotes — you cannot do this even locally. Try `git checkout master~ && git checkout master` — the files will be removed because `git` sees the files as removed from the latest commit.

Comment: How can I get around this then? It is causing config files to be wiped out when I do a pull which in turn is making coworkers of mine very frustrated. They don't fully understand how Git works (which is why these files were incorrectly checked in in the first place) so even if I try to explain what is happening the blame still falls on me when things break.

Comment: You cannot. Not removing the files is the only way. Frequent backups help to restore removed files.

Comment: "Not removing the files is the only way" -- I'm not removing the files though, Git is removing them for me. All I'm doing is adding them to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listing a file in `.gitignore` does not mean *ignore the file*, nor does it mean *don't remove the file*, or any of the things you'd like it to mean.  Nothing you do here will change that.  We'll come back to `.gitignore` near the end of this answer, but let's look first at the horrible, terrible, no-good situation you're in, which you literally cannot *fix*.  You'll have to step around it somehow.

## Here is what is wrong

The facts are that some existing commits *have* these files, and some other existing commits—those that occurred before those files existed, and those that you made after you took the files *out* of Git's index—*do not* have these files.  Nothing can change these facts.

To understand why this is the case, let's note that Git isn't *about* files.  Git is about *commits*.  Commits do store files, but it's a package deal: all or nothing.  You have a commit, and you have all of its files.  Or, you don't have the commit, and you don't have its files (so you'll use `git fetch` to add the commit to your collection, and then you have it *and* all of its files).

Moreover, the files that are inside commits are in a useless format (we'll come back to this in the next section).  They're compressed and de-duplicated, because most commits mostly have the *same* files that are in some other commit.  So Git doesn't store them *as* files, but rather as internal *objects*, which automatically de-duplicates them.

These objects are all numbered, with what Git calls a *hash ID*.  Commits in particular always get a *unique* number.  (Files, which might be duplicates of other commits' files, may have non-unique numbers, which is what de-duplicates them.)  This number is actually a cryptographic hash of the internal object contents.  This constrains Git: Not even Git can *change* a commit.

If you take a commit out, make some change, and put back the different thing, it's different and therefore gets a new and different hash ID.  The existing object remains in the Git repository, under its existing ID.  The new and improved (we hope) object is now *added* to the repository, under its new ID.  Anyone who uses the *old* ID gets the old object. Anyone who uses the *new* ID gets the new object.  This part is really pretty straightforward.

Now, the data inside a commit isn't *just* a snapshot of every file.  That's in there, yes, but there is also some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, for instance.  It also includes a time-stamp—this helps make sure every commit is totally unique, so that if two different people make the *same* commit, but for some reason, both claim to be the same *person*, they'll still get different *commits* unless they both make them at the same time (in which case, were they really two different people? Git says no).

So, there's all this metadata in each commit: author, committer, some time-stamps, log messages, and the like.  But in amongst this metadata, Git has added its own information.  Git stores, with each commit, the hash ID(s) of some set of *earlier* commits.  Most commits store exactly one hash ID, which Git calls the *parent commit*.

These parent commit hash IDs form commits into backward-looking chains.  We start at the right with the most recent (last) commit.  Rather than writing out its real hash ID, we'll just call this commit `H` (for `H`ash):

```
            <-H
```

Commit `H` has in it both a snapshot—files—and metadata, and in that metadata, commit `H` stores the hash ID of an earlier commit.  Let's pretend its hash ID is `G`, and draw it in:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Of course, commit `G` points to a still-earlier commit, which keeps on pointing backwards:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Because each commit points backwards to its parent, Git can and will find the *entire chain of commits* if Git can just find the *last* commit in the chain.  This is where branch names come in: each name in Git—branch name, tag name, remote-tracking name, and so on—stores one hash ID.  For branch names, that hash ID is the ID of the *last* commit in its chain.  This is true even if there are still-later commits in the chain, which happens normally when developing new stuff but not putting it on the main branch yet:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

Here, the `feature` branch has two more commits than the `main` branch.  Commit `J` points back to `I`, which points back to `H`, which points back to `G`, and so on.  So commits `H` and earlier are on *both* branches.  Commits `I` and `J` are only on `feature` for now, but if we like, we can "slide the name `main` forward":

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- main, feature
```

and now all commits are on both branches.

Branch names move about, and each name *by definition* picks out the *last* commit that's to be considered "on that branch".  The *commits themselves* determine what's earlier on those branches.  So it's the *commits* that matter: the names just let us *find* particular ones.  And, remember, *all* commits are frozen for all time.  No part of any existing commit can ever change.

#### Checking out a commit

As we noted above, the files inside a commit are in a format in which only Git can use them.  Even then, Git can only *read* them.  We need other programs to be able to read *and write* to our files.  The solution is simple—and is the same as that used by other version control systems: Git *copies the files out of the commit* at some point.  The copies, once out of the version control system, are now useful.  In fact, they are just plain ordinary files: *anything* on the computer can use them.  Git no longer has any control over them.

The normal, everyday way to get Git to copy the files out of some commit is to use `git checkout`.  For instance, if we have:

```
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

and we run `git checkout main`, Git will copy *all* the committed files out of commit `H`.  This also has the side effect of selecting the name `main` as our *current branch*.  Since the name `main` points to commit `H`, this means that `H` is our *current commit*.  We can draw this by attaching the special name `HEAD` to the name `main`:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

Note that we now have *two copies* of every file: there's the committed one in `H`, which we can't touch, and there's an ordinary-form everyday file in what Git calls our *working tree* or *work-tree*.

In other version control systems, these two copies of the file are the only copies you'd find.<sup>1</sup>  If you want to know what's going on, you compare the work-tree version of some file to the active committed version: whatever is different is what we've changed.  But for whatever reason—whether or not you think this is a good idea<sup>2</sup>—Git stores a *third copy of each file*<sup>3</sup> in something that Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.

This third copy of each file sits *between* the read-only committed copy and the work-tree copy.  Unlike the committed copy, it *can* be overwritten.  It's pre-compressed and pre-de-duplicated, so that it's ready to go into the *next* commit.  In fact, this is probably the best general way to think about Git's index / staging-area: it holds your *proposed next commit.*<sup>4</sup>

So, when you `git checkout` some commit, like commit `H`, Git:

- fills in its index from the commit, so that your proposed *next* commit matches;
- uses these same files to populate your working tree, so that you can see and work with your files; and
- attaches `HEAD` to the branch name, assuming you used a branch name like `main` to select the commit.  (If not, you get into "detached HEAD" mode, which we won't address here.)

If you now make changes to your working tree copies of files, you generally must also run `git add`: this tells Git *make the index copy match the working tree copy*.  For files that you updated in place, this overwrites the old index copy with a new one.  For files that you *removed*, this *removes* the index copy.  For new files, this creates a new file in Git's index.

Either way, adding files *stages* the changes, because any time you run `git commit`, Git will make its new snapshot from *whatever is in the index right then*.  If you have not altered the index, the new snapshot would exactly match the current snapshot.  In this case, Git generally requires that you use the `--allow-empty` flag: the new commit is not actually *empty*, it's just that it *matches the old one* snapshot-wise (so Git wonders: why bother? and makes you use the flag).

Whether or not you make any changes to your work-tree and/or run `git add` to update Git's index *from* your work-tree, the *current commit* remains unchanged.  Once you do make a new commit, Git:

- gathers the metadata;
- writes out the snapshot and metadata, getting a hash ID as a result; and
- writes the *hash ID* into the *current branch name*.

We end up with, e.g.:

```
          K   <-- main (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

and now there is a commit on `main` that is not on `feature`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The other read-only copies in the non-current commits would also be findable, as they are in Git, but they're not *active* the way the current commit's are.

<sup>2</sup>Other systems don't have an index, proving that it's possible to work without one.

<sup>3</sup>This "copy" is pre-de-duplicated, so most of the time, it takes almost no space.  Calling it a *copy* is thus slightly misleading.  However, unlike many of the other bits of Git that show through to the user, the fact that this "copy" is automatically de-duplicated is really well-hidden.  You can just think of this as a third copy of each file, and it all just works.  Well, until you start fiddling with internal commands like `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index`: then you need to learn about `git hash-object`.

<sup>4</sup>The index gets expanded during a conflicted merge, which means that this description is *incomplete*, but it's at least not *wrong*. :-)  The index also has a role in making Git go fast, which is why it has the old name *cache*.  You mostly see this name in option flags these days, like `git rm --cached`.

---

#### Switching between commits that have different files

Let's say that between commit `H` and commit `I` we *remove* a file.  Let's say further that we put it on a new branch X:

```
git checkout main
git checkout -b X
git rm somefile
git commit -m 'remove a file'
```

Commit `H` *has* a file named `somefile` and commit `I` *lacks* a file named `somefile`.

When we `git checkout main`, file `somefile` has to *come back*.  Git copies it from commit `H` to Git's index and our work-tree, and now we have the file.

When we `git checkout X` to move back to commit `I`, file `somefile` has to *go away*.  Git removes it from Git's index *and from our work-tree*.

**This property is determined by the set of files in the two commits.**  I would say *entirely*, but if you experiment a bit, you'll see that Git's *removal* of file `somefile` is conditional:

```
git checkout main          # file somefile comes back
git rm --cached somefile   # take somefile out of Git's index
```

Because we use `git rm --cached` here, Git removes `somefile` from its index, but **does not touch our work-tree copy**.  If we now run:

```
git checkout X
```

—remember, commit `I`, selected by branch name `X`, *lacks* the file `somefile`—Git *doesn't* remove `somefile` from our working tree.  The reason is that after `git rm --cached`, file `somefile` is *untracked*.

#### Untracked files

**An untracked file, in Git, is simply a file that is in your working tree right now, but not in Git's index right now.**  That's it—that is the entire definition—but it has a lot of consequences, including the fact that `git commit` would not include the untracked file in the new commit, and including the lack of *removal* that we just saw.

Because your working tree *is* **yours**, you can create and destroy files in it whenever you like.

Because Git's index is Git's, Git can put files there—but we know *when* it will do which thing:

- When you `git add` a file, Git adds or removes the file based on what that file looks like in your working tree.
- When you `git checkout` a commit, Git adds or removes files to/from the index based on whether those files are in the other commit.
- When you run `git rm --cached`, Git removes files from Git's index as instructed.
- Other cases not covered here include how `git merge` manipulates Git's index, how `git reset` and `git restore` work, and so on.

So, to some extent, *you* control which files are in Git's index—but they tend to mirror commits.

#### The index and working tree are specific to each clone

Git is a little bit ambivalent as to whether the index and working tree are included in a repository.  Specifically, `git init --bare` makes a repository that has no working tree, but such a repository still has an index.  (It probably shouldn't, but it does.)  There is also the `git worktree add` command, since Git 2.5, which adds a pair—a working tree *and* an index—to a repository.  So there can be multiple index-and-work-tree sets in any given repository.

It's clear enough, though, that `git clone` *does not* copy the index and work-tree of any existing repository (regardless of how many exist in that repository).  So the index, or all indices, and work-tree(s) are private to each clone.  You can't control any other repository's index and work-tree directly: you have to leave that to whoever might be operating Git on the other machine (assuming the other clone is on another machine).

#### About `.gitignore`

The `.gitignore` file is misnamed.  A better name would be `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-files-if-they-are-untracked-and-if-they-are-untracked-and-I-use-an-en-masse-add-command-do-not-add-them-to-the-index-either`.

When we run `git status`, Git *complains* about untracked files.  It gets very whiny!  This is quite annoying, because with a work-tree being an ordinary directory, and the kinds of software that we use, we run programs that create lots of build artifacts *in* our work-trees.  This leaves tons of untracked files.  The `git status` command becomes noisy, and our productivity plummets.

To get `git status` to *shut the ____ up*, we can list these expected build products in a `.gitignore` file.  **This has no effect on whether those files are in the index right now.**  But if they're *not* in the index—if they *are* untracked right now—then `git status` *won't* complain about them.

Of course, if `git status` doesn't complain, it would be really nice if `git add .` also "worked right", by *not adding them*.  So that's the second main effect of listing a file in `.gitignore`: if the file *isn't* already tracked—if it's not in the index *now*—and we run `git add .`, we want Git to *not add it*.

If the file is already in the index (is tracked), listing it in `.gitignore` has no effect on `git status` and `git add`: the file's status *will* be checked, and the `git add` *will* add the file.<sup>5</sup>  So for already-tracked files, `.gitignore` is no help.  That's why the file's name isn't really right.  But a more correct name would be unusable, so `.gitignore` it is.

Listing a file in `.gitignore` has one more side effect: it gives Git permission to *clobber* the file.  This mostly involves checking out an old commit that *does* contain the file, when the file is being untracked-and-ignored.  The checkout proceeds, and now you have the *tracked* file out, with the untracked one's data having been literally destroyed.  So the *real* full name might be `.git-about-some-files-that-may-be-untracked-and-what-to-do-if-they-are:do-not-complain-and-do-not-auto-add-but-do-feel-free-to-destroy-these-files`, or something.  (But colon characters are disallowed on many Microsoft systems.)

---

<sup>5</sup>There are some index flags—part of the *cache* aspect of the index—that one can abuse to prevent `git status` from looking, and `git add` from adding.  These are the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree flags.  They are not designed for this purpose, hence the *abuse* notion above, and they don't help with the particular problem to which this is an answer, but they're worth mentioning.

---

#### What you must do

You have several options.  The most drastic, but easiest to enforce and perhaps easiest to do, is: make a whole new Git repository.  Be careful *never* to add these files, so that they *never* become tracked and therefore never become a problem.  Move all your systems to the new Git repository, abandoning (and eventually destroying) the old Git repository.

Alternatively, you can do a minimal update: make new commits that, compared to the old commits, *remove* the files.  Then, go around to *every deployment* and update those systems by hand, carefully *preserving* the files while making them untracked.  You can use the `git rm --cached` trick, or save the files outside the working tree during the checkout, or whatever else you like.  Any of these methods works.  Then be *very careful never to return to the poisonous commits that will make those files tracked.*

In between these two options, you can use a history rewriting tool (filter-branch, filter-repo, The BFG, whatever you like) to take your existing commits and turn them into new-and-improved commits in which those files have never been committed.  This is a lot like the first and/or third option: you still have to go, carefully, to each deployment and update it, because the rewritten repository is, in effect, a *new* repository.  It has the downside that someone with the old (pre-rewrite) repository can easily accidentally re-introduce the bad commits, if the histories sync up.  (Whether they do depends on what's in the first few commits ever made and/or how you do the history rewrite.)

If you have full control of the software, the *best* option is usually this:

- Move important data that can/should be version-controlled, if any, to a new file name.  This might, for instance, be `config.defaults`.
- Move important data that *must not* be version controlled—because it differs on each site—to a new file name.  This might, for instance, be `config.site`.
- Make sure `config.site` does not appear in any past, present, or future commit.  *Do* list it in `.gitignore` so that it won't accidentally get added and committed.
- Update all installations to have a correct (and by definition, untracked) `config.site` file.
- Distribute the new revision.  All sites now use the defaults and per-site configuration.  None of the old commits need to change.

You can't change the past, but there's no need to do that.

Comment: I like this new stroppy exasperated persona.

Comment: This may be the best answer I have ever seen. Thank you for all of the time and effort you spent on this. I am thinking option 2 is what I want to go with (we will probably never go back to the "poisoned" commits once we get it right) but I'm not exactly sure what commands I need to use in order to "carefully update" each server with the new commit without removing the files that are now listed in `.gitignore`. Would I do a `git fetch` and then somehow play with the index to stop it from removing the files before I checkout the new commit?

Comment: If it were me, I'd (1) save the files somewhere (`mkdir /tmp/save; cp <files> /tmp/save/` or similar) just in case; (2) run `git fetch; git log origin/<name>; git rm --cached <paths>; git merge --ff-only`. The fetch+merge is just an expanded out `git pull --ff-only` which lets me insert commands in between: in this case, `git log` to make sure I see what I'm expecting to see, `git rm --cached` to attempt to make sure I don't get the poison effect, and then the final merge-for-fast-forward-checkout-effect.If all goes well, I can `rm -r /tmp/save`, if not, I still have the files...

Comment: Okay I found a workflow that works well!

Fetch remote content:
`git fetch`...

Checkout JUST .gitignore from the remote:
`git checkout origin/master .gitignore`...

Remove ignored files from the index:
`git rm -r --cached .`...

Merge the changes:
`git merge --ff-only origin/master`...

After taking these steps the files are updated and the ignored files are not removed!